# Figures three spaces after and before text

Tags: spacing, floats

For my dissertation I'm required to place the floats with a space of three lines after and three lines before the text. Is there a way to do this other than manually inserting the paragraph breaks before and after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the lengths associated with vertical spacing around floats (from the [`layouts` package](//ctan.org/pkg/layouts), section **6.2 Detailed float layout**):

[image]

You should be able to set the lengths `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep` (possibly also `\floatsep`) to `3\baselineskip` - the equivalent of three lines of text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}

% For reference, here are the defaults, from the LaTeX kernel:
%  https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co
% \setlength\floatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
% \setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
% \setlength\intextsep   {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}

% Adjust vertical separation between floats and...
\setlength{\floatsep}{3\baselineskip}% ...other floats
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3\baselineskip}% ...text above or below
\setlength{\intextsep}{3\baselineskip}% ...text above and below

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!thb]
  \caption{A top figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \caption{An in-text figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-5]

\begin{figure}[!b]
  \caption{A bottom figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-9]

\end{document}
```

Note that the default lengths for these have some shrink/stretch to accommodate for the vertical page construction to have some flexibility. You may consider adding those back, although it may reduce your three lines of space slightly on some pages.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: @Rob28: I see you [asked a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/662479/5764) already... Good.